# How to set the property 'maxActive' with only MyBatis?

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

When using MyBatis, I can simply set the 'username', 'password' with the tag <property/>, like <property name="username" value="${local.username}"/>.

However, when I want to set another property named 'maxActive', I got an error: "Unknown DataSource property: maxActive".

After read the relevant documents, I indeed realize that MyBatis does not allow to set 'maxActive' via tag <property/>.

Meanwhile, I did found many answers relevant, but they are all talking about 'Spring+MyBatis'.

So would you please tell me How can I set the property 'maxActive' with ONLY MyBatis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxActive` is a property of Tomcat connection pool not mybatis. You can configure the corresponding property in mybatis `POOLED` datasource like this:

```
<dataSource type="POOLED">
  <property name="driver" value="${driver}"/>
  <property name="url" value="${url}"/>
  <property name="username" value="${username}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${password}"/>
  <property name="poolMaximumActiveConnections" value="20"/>
</dataSource>
```

Other properties are described in [mybatis documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#properties).